# Laravel 10 - mutators and accessors don't work

Tags: php, laravel, accessor, mutators, laravel-10

I have a problem with the accessors and mutators in laravel 10. In my first project, they work, but in the second, they don't.

**Model**

```
protected function name(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn(string $value) => strtoupper($value),
        set: fn(string $value) => strtolower($value),
    );
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(StoreRoleRequest $request)
{
    Role::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'guard_name' => "web",
    ]);
    
    return $this->index();
}
```

The store function and index function work but the mutator and accessor are not triggered. I verified the table field name and tried to store it without a store request.

Comment: Code looks ok; could it be a cache issue? Check the database record to see how it's stored. Also check in `artisan tinker` with simple code like `Role::first()->name` and check if it's being altered.

Answer (score -3):

please try it's working with laravel 10

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

public function categoryImage(): Attribute
{
    return new Attribute(
        
        get: fn ($value) => URL::to('/').'/'.$value
    );
}
```

Comment: "works for me" along with a completely unrelated piece of code is not a very helpful response.